# Numpy datetime64[D] array to polars date series/column

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, python-polars

Numpy datetime array seems to be converted to object series in Polars, but numerical or string arrays keeps the proper format when converted to pl.Series. Am I using it wrong or could this be a bug etc.?

In:

```
datetime_array = np.array(['2022-02-11', '2022-02-11', '2022-02-11','2022-02-10','2022-02-11', '2022-02-11'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Out:

```
array(['2022-02-11', '2022-02-11', '2022-02-11', '2022-02-10',
       '2022-02-11', '2022-02-11'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Converting to series:

In:

```
pl.Series(datetime_array)
```

Out:

```
shape: (6,)
Series: '' [o][object]
[
    2022-02-11
    2022-02-11
    2022-02-11
    2022-02-10
    2022-02-11
    2022-02-11
]
```

If I'm trying to define the dtype in the series to be pl.Date or pl.Utf8 it raises an exception as below

In:

```
pl.Series(datetime_array, dtype=pl.Date)
```

Out:

```
InvalidOperationError: cannot cast array of type ObjectChunked to arrow datatype
```

Work around for this I have found is to convert numpy datetime array to string type in numpy, and only then convert to Polars series. Then using .str.strptime() in Polars to convert back to date type.

In:

```
pl.Series(np.datetime_as_string(datetime_array)).str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Out:

```
shape: (6,)
Series: '' [date]
[
    2022-02-11
    2022-02-11
    2022-02-11
    2022-02-10
    2022-02-11
    2022-02-11
]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that polars doesn't map datetime64[D] to pl.Date().  That being said, you can do much better than converting to strings and back.

Simply do:

```
pl.Series(datetime_array.astype('datetime64[ms]')).cast(pl.Date())
```